# Chrome Developer Tools: JS Interpreter?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Sorry if I missed something and this is a silly question...but can I enter arbitrary javascript in the developer tools console (like I can with firebug)? It seems that I can interact with the DOM, console.log, etc., but I'm wondering if there's a way to enter code in to try things out like one would do with an interpreter?

EDIT:

So I was thrown because of the undefined return when I did a simple declaration and assignment, but yeah, it DOES work as a simple shell as I asked:

```
var i = 123;
undefined
console.log(i);
123
undefined
for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) { console.log(j); }
0
1
2
3
```

My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interact with the environment of the current page. You can then try out some code in a 'command-line' kind of way. Do post a feature request if you want more functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I was thrown when I saw undefined returned after assignment. Thanks.